# How to render bitmaps effectively using OpenGL ES on Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, opengl-es

My app generates 25 bitmaps(1080 * 1920) per second, I try to render them by converting them into texture(calling `createTexture()`), and then use the default render mode(calling `OnDrawFrame()` 50 times per second). However, my app crashes several seconds after launched. Is it correct to use OpenGL ES in this way? Or is there any better way to render bitmaps effectively?
The main code of my render is as following:

```
    public abstract class BaseRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{


        public BaseRenderer(Context context, String vertex, String fragment){           
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
            GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
            GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            mProgram= ShaderUtils.createProgram(mContext.getResources(),vertex,fragment);
            glHPosition=GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram,"vPosition");
            glHCoordinate=GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram,"vCoordinate");
            glHTexture=GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram,"vTexture");
            glHMatrix=GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram,"vMatrix");
            onDrawCreatedSet(mProgram);
        }


        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

            onDrawSet();

            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(glHMatrix,1,false,mMVPMatrix,0);
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(glHPosition);
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(glHCoordinate);
            GLES20.glUniform1i(glHTexture, 0);

            textureId=createTexture();

            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(glHPosition,2,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,false,0,bPos);
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(glHCoordinate,2,GLES20.GL_FLOAT,false,0,bCoord);

            GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);
        }

        public abstract void onDrawSet();
        public abstract void onDrawCreatedSet(int mProgram);

        private int createTexture(){
            int[] texture=new int[1];
            if(mBitmap!=null&&!mBitmap.isRecycled()){
                GLES20.glGenTextures(1,texture,0);
                GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[0]);
                GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
                GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
                GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, mBitmap, 0);
                return texture[0];
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```